# mt_rand PHP - line of several numbers

Tags: php

is it possible to customize mt_rand to a function which gives me a line of numbers without repeats.

For example `mt_rand(1,5)` should give me 4,2,3,1,5 or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This achieves what you ask in your question:

```
$results = range(1, 5);
shuffle($results);
```

For more complex needs, you can use [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker).

For instance the [randomElements() method](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/blob/3860fbe35dff991f39640a38f51807e2594c9783/src/Faker/Provider/Base.php#L162), here picking 5 non-duplicate numbers in the 1-10 range:

```
$faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

$results = $faker->randomElements(range(1, 10), 5, false);
```

(though, this can also be done with regular PHP easily:)

```
$pool = range(1, 10);
shuffle($pool);

$results = array_slice($pool, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Range and shuffle.

```
$arr =Range(1,5); // array with items 1->5

Shuffle($arr); // shuffle them 

Var_dump($arr);// output
// Or
Echo implode(",", $arr); // to match your expected output
```

https://3v4l.org/Usa65